# How do I use an enum as a return value in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, enums

I can't find an answer to this in my searches.  How do I return an enum as the result of a function?  It feels like a stupid question that I just can't figure out.

```
enum getCardObjectType(val object) {
    if(val is wantedObjectType)
      return CardType.Link;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of an Enum is:

```
enum CardType {
    link,
    option2
}
```

your function should be something like this:

```
CardType getCardObjectType(val object) {
    if(val is wantedObjectType)
      return CardType.Link;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `CardType` as return type.

The fact that CardType is an enum doesn't change the syntax here, the type is just  CardType.